# Can I add words to a string using an if/else statement in Java?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Currently, I'm attempting to make a very basic blackjack game that will also tell the player what is in their hand and what is in the computer's hand after each turn is taken.

```
if(y == 1){
        acecomp = true;
        comphand + "Ace";
    }
    else
```

My snippet of code looks like this, and obviously what i'm asking it to do isn't possible, otherwise i wouldn't be here.
Is there any way that I can make the if/else statement add a word to the computer's hand?

Comment: Did you mean to write `comphand += "Ace"`?

Comment: `comphand += "Ace"` or `comphand = comphand + "Ace"` works.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `comphand + "Ace"` you aren't assigning it to anything.

Try this:

```
comphand = comphand + "Ace";
```

Or as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested:

```
compahand += "Ace"
```

Which is the Java shorthand for "Add and assign".

Comment: Any time! Glad I could help.

Comment: lol I am that horse with no name who suggested the edit though.

Comment: Sorry, saw his comment up there first and rejected your edit because it crossed my own. No harm intended.

Comment: @Todd that's totally fine. Not offended or anything. was just too funny

Answer (score 1):

depending on whether or not you have a lot of words to add to a root word, the stringbuilder should be a good option too.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(comphand); 
if(y == 1){
   sb.append("ace"); 
}else{...}

comphand = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called *appending* a string - just so you know for future reference when searching for things like this.

In Java, it's as easy as doing math. Here's an example:

```
String s = "Hello!";
s = s + " How are you?";
System.out.println(s);
```

This will print out "Hello! How are you?".

But let me address a different concern. If you're doing a hand of cards, you make want to us an `ArrayList` - they are used like this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> computerHand = new ArrayList<String>();

        computerHand.add("Ace");
        computerHand.add("8");
        computerHand.add("7");
        computerHand.add("King");

       for(int i = 0; i < computerHand.size();i++) {
           System.out.println(computerHand.get(i));
       }

       computerHand.remove("Ace"); //OR computerHand.remove(0) <---where index is 0

    }   
}
```